Reading from System.in in multiple threads
I have the following problem:

method1 that keeps reading from System.in and sending it via Socket
method2 that only reads from System.in when a error occurs in it

When I have a problem in method2, I have to press ENTER twice, because, even it closing the socket, the readLine() on method1 was already executed, so it first read the line for method1, then it takes the input for method2.
Edit:
The method1 is constantly receiving messages from the socket and method2 is sending everything I type on console via Socket. But when the receive of messages fail, I want to just ask if the client wants to connect to other server, but the method1 already read the line, so the first time i type goes to the now useless method1, then the second line goes correctly to method2
What can I do in this case?
Observation: I know in the example I can make the reader as a class property. Just made this way to make it easier to understand
public class App {

    public void method1() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            String line;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while (!socket.isClosed() && line = bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
                //Keeps reading from the System.in and sending to the Socket
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void method2() {
        try {
            //Keeps receiving messages from the Socket
        } catch (Exception e) {
            socket.close();
            String line;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            //Asks if the user want to connect to other server
        }
    }
}


What does “OBS” mean?

You may get a better response with more explanation. For one thing, using the console (System.in) across threads makes no practical sense.

There are not 2 System.in, so either you use bufferedReader.readLine(); line = bufferedReader.readLine(); (I unload the buffer and then read... ugly) or you don't use System.in.

@BasilBourque OBS means Observation, just like some annotation. The method1 is constantly receiving messages from the socket and method2 is sending everything I type on console via Socket. But when the receive of messages fail, I want to just ask if the client wants to connect to other server, but the method1 already readed the line, so the first time i type goes to the now useless method1, then the second line goes correctly to method2. If you think that there's a better way to do this, it would be of great help.

@MarcePuente I'm sorry, I can't understand what you said. I already told that I'm using two Buffers for System.in just so the example becomes easier to understand, in reality I'm using only one for both, is that what you meant?

@Kobra: Please, do not comment with clarifications, instead incorporate those clarifications into the question post itself. On Stack Overflow we expect the question post itself to be understandable without reading the comments.

@Kobra, I just wanted to point out that you can't get any other behavior.

@Tsyvarev Edited the post, thanks!

From your description, I understand that you want to loop through some plain text from System.in and when encountering errors, call method2 to close the Socket. I think you can establish a check to first see if the specific line would throw an error or not.
Again, I assume that the error happens when sending to the Socket. Therefore, I think you can create a dummy instance that would get the problematic line instead of sending it directly to the current one. This way, you assure that you can predict an error line and keep it away from the main instance.
Another suggestion would be to have your own way of identifying errors, instead of having to send lines directly to the client and see if they worked or not, you can have a method that would return whether the line is problematic or not based on some test cases.
I am sorry if this won't work for you, but I tried my best as I am a beginner :)
More details would help as well, because with the ones provided by you I can't be sure of coding a solution, as I don't know the full problem.

Thanks Grebla, but I can't do this in my case. The think is that, the Error actually occurs when the Socket connection is disconnected by the other user, so it's kinda unpredictable, and the only way I found was with Exception Treatment, so I can't predict it and cannot do it that way. But thanks!

I’m sorry I couldn’t help you! I will try coming later and maybe take a closer look. I hope you will solve it as fast as possible!
